Relationship between return period and probability
As I understand it, the return period of an event (such as an earthquake or a flood) is the average time between two consecutive occurrences of that event. The probability of occurrence of an event with a return period of $r$ occurring is $1/r$. For example, if the return period of an intense earthquake is $10$ years, the probability that the earthquake will occurr in each year is $1/10$.
I don't quite understand why the probability of occurrence is reciprocal to the return period. For example if something usually happens every $10$ years, why is the probability of its occurrence in any given year is $1/10$?

There's more than one possible modelling setting here.
First, you might have a process where events occur pretty much independently. Whether a hurricane hits central Florida this year is more or less independent of whether it hit last year. So if it happens about every 100 years on average, the chance is equal and independent every year, and this comes to a 1/100 probability each year. The time between events follows a geometric distribution (if we're counting whole years) or an exponential distribution (if we're measuring time continuously), which is the only distribution for events with no "memory". Sometimes you might get two hurricanes hitting Tampa in one year; sometimes it might be 200 years between them.
At the other extreme, you might have a regular event, like a daily train. The train comes at a fixed time every day, so there's 24 hours between trains. If you arrive at the station without knowing anything about the train schedule there's a 1/24 chance that you arrived in the hour before the train, a 1/24 chance that you arrived between one and two hours before, and so on.  Even though the distribution in the long run is regular, with exactly one train per day at a fixed time, your random arrival time and ignorance of the schedule means there's a 1/24 chance each hour of the train arriving.
Many events are in between these extremes.  For example, major earthquakes on New Zealand's Alpine Fault are somewhat regular. They have a mean recurrence rate of 291 years, plus or minus 23 years. Strain accumulates in the fault, then the rock ruptures and releases the strain. It's not perfectly regular, like a daily train, but it's more regular than an geometric/exponential distribution.  It makes sense to say the Alpine Fault is overdue for a major quake, when it wouldn't make sense to say Tampa is overdue for a major hurricane.
If you didn't know how long ago the last major quake was, it would make sense to say the chance is 1/291 per year, by the train argument, but since we do know the date of the last quake (312 years ago) we can do better than using the long-run return time.  Geologists using a lognormal distribution model say there's about a 1/65 chance per year of a quake at the moment.
So, in summary, turning a K-year return time into a 1/K-per-year risk requires either

different years are approximately independent, as with hurricanes; or
we don't know where in recurrence distribution we are starting, as with trains.
If the return distribution isn't independent over years and you know where you are in the cycle, you won't get this simple correspondence

